# Problem in a Typescript project cloning a GitHub Project, puppeteer, ssl

Tags: typescript, github, ssl, puppeteer, git-fork

I was hoping you could help me, I've been trying to make an anchor protocol clone (I'm not a developer, so excuse me if I ask dumb questions). What I did was the following:

1. I copied their Github repo using git clone.
2. I did

```
yarn install
```

3. I did

```
mkcert -install,
```

and then

```
mkcert localhost 127.0.0.1
```

in my project folder.

4. Set the variables (LOCALHOST_HTTPS_CERT) of the ssl certificates in .env to the location of mine.

At this point I thought that this was all I had to do to be able to execute: yarn run app:start And that I could have anchor protocol in my local web and be able to study it.

However when I do yarn run app:start the following happens:

1.- Chromium opens and says the following although it already has the permission granted: "Do you want to the application Chromium.app to accept incoming network connections?" Even if I put "allow" the Chrome tray is closed.

2.- A window in iterm2 gives me the following message:

```
iancid@192 ~ % cd /Users/iancid/Desktop/Anchor/anchor-
web-app/app; yarn run app:dev:browser;
Error: net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID at https://localhost:3000
     at navigate (/Users/iancid/Desktop/Anchor/anchor-web-app/node_modules/puppeteer/src/common/FrameManager.ts:218:13)
     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
     at async FrameManager.navigateFrame (/Users/iancid/Desktop/Anchor/anchor-web-app/node_modules/puppeteer/src/common/FrameManager.ts:188:17)
     at async Frame.goto (/Users/iancid/Desktop/Anchor/anchor-web-app/node_modules/puppeteer/src/common/FrameManager.ts:765:12)
     at async Page.goto (/Users/iancid/Desktop/Anchor/anchor-web-app/node_modules/puppeteer/src/common/Page.ts:1766:12)
     at async /Users/iancid/Desktop/Anchor/anchor-web-app/app/scripts/start.ts:25:3
```

3.- If I look for the local link to open the page "https://localhost:3000/". The page is not detected as secure (as if the ssl certificate was not valid) I put it to access the page even though it is insecure and looks blank. When I put "refresh" it is possible to see the page for a second.

Thank you very much for the help, try to be as specific as possible. If you have any questions I will answer immediately. Thank you very much again.

I was expecting to see the anchor app in my local server working normally. I suppose the problem is with my ssl certificate or with the puppeteer, but I have no idea.